# javascript references order in wicket 1.5

Tags: java, javascript, wicket-1.5

i have a problem with the javascript references in my page since migrating to wicket 1.5.
i'm contributing few js files to the header from a wicket page, and then useing them in the page's components.

the problem is that if i use wicket 1.5 way to contribute js - adding a behavior which contributes the js in its renderHead method, the renderHead of the components that are using the js is called before the renderHead of the page or of the page's added behaviors, which of course leads to Uncaught ReferenceError.

any idea how to control the order of the js?
thank you in advance

update:

after intensive search i found that what i'm willing to do is practically impossible in wicket 1.5. as explained [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-2693) wicket guys have decided to reverse the order the js and css is rendered - deepest components first and then container (instead the other way around - which was the behavior until 1.5). the rendering strategy is not configurable by any mean.

i wouldn't expect them to do such a change, especially without letting the option to override this configuration. in my case, for example, i have tens of components that are using jquery, that up until now was added from the page. now it seems that i'll have to change all my existing components to contribute jquery (and any other required js).
quite harsh, and definitely not backward compatible.

Comment: FYI in Wicket 6, ResourceReference can define it's dependencies. There is even PriorityHeaderItem for wrapping important HeaderItems. Sadly, nothing like that backported to 1.5.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wicket documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/creating-a-behavior-to-use-a-javascript-library.html):

[quote]

- In the head tag, you would provide your implementation in renderHead
- Just after our component render, you would override onRendered or rendered as in the code example above
- Just before our component render, you would override onComponentTag

[/quote]

Comment: i don't see how this helps me as:
1. all my js is contributed to the header
2. i have tens of components that uses the js contributed by the page
3. i have no intention to get into wicket's internal and write the js string directly into the response but rather use wicket's abstraction of adding js.
is there a reasonable way to control the order of the header conribution?